# Current position for regex matching in perl

Tags: regex, perl, matching

i want to subsequently extract the text snippet between two paths
in a long string.

Therefore, I use something like this:

```
while($data=~ m/\"(.:\\.*?)\".:\\/sg){...}
```

`` `\".:\\(.*?) `` is a path with a `"` before.
and, since the part between the two paths can be any characters,
I finish the regular expression with the start of the next path: `\".:\\`

Unfortunately like this the code skips always one match. I believe,
that this is, because the subsequent search will start after the last `\".:\\` and therefore it will only find the next one.

How can I make sure, that the poisition pointer for the search is set
back to before the last part of the regular expression (before: `\".:\\`)

Edit:

```
"y:\car\main.cs@@jung" "Added format of version number to all sub-parts.

"Hallo Peter"

@@@ "tool kit" @@@"

"y:\car\main.cs@@kkla" (lkaskdn awdiwj)

"The filter "function of the new version works with Excel 2007"only,
but is the correct filter structure.

@@@ "Huihu boy" @@@"
```

This file should give me two results in $1:

1.

```
y:\car\main.cs@@jung" "Added format of version number to all sub-parts.

"Hallo Peter"

@@@ "tool kit" @@@"
```

2.

```
y:\car\main.cs@@kkla" (lkaskdn awdiwj)

"The filter "function of the new version works with Excel 2007"only,
but is the correct filter structure.

@@@ "Huihu boy" @@@"
```

but it would only give me the first.

Comment: Hi, you are right it is low.
but what, if the answers are not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).  This matches something after your pattern without including the "something" in your match.  The syntax is:

```
(?=...)
```

I don't have sample data for your regex, so here is a simple example instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "foobarbarbarnbar";

print "Regular matches: ";
#regular matching
while ($string =~ /(\w+?)bar/g)
{
   print " $1"; 
}
#lookahead
print "\nLookahead matches: ";
while ($string =~ /(\w+?)(?=bar)/g)
{
   print " $1"; 
}
```

Output:

```
Regular matches:  foo bar n 
Lookahead matches:  foo bar bar barn
```

Comment: great! It is really hard to find something if you do not know these expressions as lookahead match ;)
Thank you so much!